# How to find the primitive elements of $F_{13}$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I am trying to work out how to find the primitive elements of $F_{13}$.

I know the primitive element are $2,-6,6,2$ but I am not sure how to get to this answer.

Does it have something to do with the inverses of the elements of $F_{13}$?

What is the general method to find the primitive elements?

Comment: Consider powers: $2^1=2$, $2^2=4$, $2^3=8$, $2^4=3$, $2^5=6$, $2^6=12$, $2^7=11$, $2^8=9$, $2^9=5$, $2^{10}=10$, $2^{11}=7$, $2^{12}=1$.  Since you get all the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{13}^\times$ as powers of $2$, it is a primitive element.

Comment: Some elements to add to the interesting answer of @Michal Burr that can be helpful if you work on any finite field : the multiplicative group of any finite field is cyclic (Wedderburn theorem), and the exponent of a primitive element $p$ (such as the exponents of 2 here) that give x is called the discrete logarithm of x base $p$.

Comment: I think if you're not sure what to do, you need to think about the definition of "primitively element" more.

Comment: Also, once you've found one primitive element $\alpha$ of the field $\mathbb F_q$, we have that all the other primitive elements are exactly $\alpha^k$, where $\gcd(k,q-1)=1$.

Comment: Where primitively$\equiv$primitive via my autocorrection.